# Filter unwanted characters from a column in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have a Phone number column in my table with values only being numbers and no special characters. for one of the column I got a value coming in as ":1212121212".

I will need to filter this record and any records coming in with any special characters in teradata. Can anyone help on this.

I have tried the below solutions but it is not working

```
where (REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_name, '[0-9]+')<>1 or column_name is null )
```

Comment: Instead of checking if there is special character in string, you can check if the value contains only number

Comment: @DaleK - Sorry, will correct it next time.

Comment: @Hana - Thanks, i tried it and it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jonas. Since I need only numeric values and the length should be 10, I tried the below and it worked. This would ignore all the additional special characters.

```
(regexp_similar(Column,'[0-9]{10}')=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL Server DB's, you can use `TRYCAST` to find those entries having non numeric characters:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM yourtable
WHERE TRY_CAST(column_name AS INT) IS NULL;
```

In Teradata DB's, you can use `TO_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM yourtable
WHERE TO_NUMBER(column_name) IS NULL;
```

If you want to stay close to your attempt, can use `LIKE` to find not numeric entries:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM yourtable
WHERE column_name LIKE '%[^0-9]%';
```

Note this could get slow when your table has very many rows.

Comment: ISNUMERIC is a terribly misleading name and function - not recommended at all.

Comment: You're right, TRYCAST should work better here. Updated the answer.